# how can I alert on Pod Eviction or Failed && Evicted pods in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus-operator

I can see from the pod description that my pod "Failed" due to being "Evicted" due to Memory Pressure. but how can i test for too many "Failed && Evicted" pods with prometheus alert rules or some other means?

I have Prometheus Operator installed, I can see metrics for Failed Pods but not Failed and Evicted

kubectl describe pod gives:

```
Name:         besteffort-evictme-001
Namespace:    skyfii
Priority:     0
Node:         ip-172-17-2-169.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal/
Start Time:   Fri, 24 Sep 2021 15:28:53 +1000
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
Status:       Failed
Reason:       Evicted
Message:      The node was low on resource: memory. Container termination-demo-container was using 17165108Ki, which exceeds its request of 0. 
IP:           
IPs:          <none>
Containers:
```

the prometheus rule :

```
kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Failed"} > 0
```

shows the failed pod

```
kube_pod_status_phase{endpoint="http",instance="172.17.3.141:8080",job="kube-state-metrics",namespace="skyfii",phase="Failed",pod="besteffort-evictme-001",service="prometheus-kube-state-metrics"}
```

but nothing shows up for

```
kube_pod_container_status_terminated_reason{reason="Evicted"} > 0
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks
Karl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So it seems I need to update my version of `kube-prometheus-stack` helm chart.

The "Evicted" `Reason` we see in pod description is hanging off podStatus
[image]

newer `kube-prometheus-stack` versions which brings in the later version (v.2) of kube-state-metrics (v.2) which in turn exposes the [kube_pod_status_reason](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/pod-metrics.md)

I'll upgrade then refactor my prometheus query to use this new metric and post back the answer when I get it working.

cheers
Karl

upgrading to kube-prometheus-stack v 18.1.0 allowed me to do this:-
[image]

so I'll be able to craft the query I need now

I added this to my prometheus alertmanager rules by adding it to the
`prometheusAdditionalRulesMap` section of the kube-prometheus-stack's Values.yaml

```
      - name: kubernetes-container-evictions

        rules:

        # Mem pressure evicted pods are left in a Failed state, alert if we see too many failed pods

        # NB you will need to delete the failed pods after investigating

        - alert: FailedEvictedPods

          expr: sum by(namespace, pod) (kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Failed"} > 0 and on(namespace, pod) kube_pod_status_reason{reason="Evicted"} > 0) > 0

          for: 10m

          labels:

            severity: warning

          annotations:

            message: 'Failed Evicted pod:{{ $labels.pod }} namespace:{{ $labels.namespace }}'


        - alert: TooManyEvictedPods

          expr: sum(kube_pod_status_reason{reason="Evicted"}) >= 2

          labels:

            severity: high

          annotations:

            message: 'Too many Failed Evicted Pods: {{ $value }}'
```

and now I get the alerts I wanted :-)